# python datetime formatting confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone

Correct me if I'm wrong, but assume we have the date:

```
Wed, 27 Jun 2018 11:20:33 -0500
```

If we use the datetime in python to convert this (`datetime.datetime.strptime('Wed, 27 Jun 2018 11:20:33 -0500', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')`), this generates a time 1 hour greater than UTC, which comes out to 12:20:33. However, in reality shouldn't this be UTC-5 (minus 5 hours). I am taking this date format that is being stored in an XML file. Many of them have -0500 or +0000 at the end of the timestamp. Am I missing something here?

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('Wed, 27 Jun 2018 11:20:33 -0500',
                                 '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
print(dt.timestamp())

print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(dt.timestamp())).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It correctly generated the timezone here

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('Wed, 27 Jun 2018 11:20:33 -0500', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 27, 11, 20, 33, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 68400)))
```

`datetime.timedelta(-1, 68400)` means -5 hours which is correct.

You should add to your question all steps that lead to your "incorrect" result, and what you expect instead.

EDIT: Now that you edited your question - your problem comes from the utilization of `.timestamp()` and `.fromtimestamp()` - those methods are timezone naive, so they don't preserve timezone information.

You have to store it yourself if you want:

```
t = datetime.datetime.strptime('Wed, 27 Jun 2018 11:20:33 -0500', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')

stamp = t.timestamp()
stored_zone = t.tzinfo

t2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stamp, tz=stored_zone)
```

This will generate the equivalent `datetime` object again, with the same timezone, so `t == t2`

```
t3 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stamp, tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

This will generate the same datetime again, but in utc timezone, so it will show up as 16:20 but internally it is the same time, still `t == t3`!!! Just the timezone is different but both represent the same moment in time.

Timezones are confusing. I recommend reading the docs multiple times and testing all the things. Or just use pytz.

Comment: so what im passing in -0500, that has no relation to what python is converting?

Comment: @dataviews I don't understand the question. You passed -0500 in the string. `strptime` parsed it and added to the datetime a timezone info of minus five hours. What is incorrect?

Comment: I've now added my code. When I run my code, the -0500 gives +1 hour, not minus 5 hours.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the -5 hours however. I;m not sure why this is happening on my end.

Comment: @dataviews are you CST? `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` generates datetimes in local time, not in UTC, so -0500 would appear +1 hr to you.

Comment: I can replicate the problem that @dataviews describes . I am in Eastern time. I also got a result of `2018-06-27 12:20:33` **but** I can also replicate the solution

Comment: I understand what i did wrong now. I tried your solution, but I get: 2018-06-27 11:20:33-05:00 as the output.

Comment: @dataviews added some clarification, hope that helps

Comment: Now I get 16:20:33

Comment: @dataviews exactly, 11 is 16 - 5; so when you change time zone to utc, you get 16!

Comment: So if the time shows TIMESHOWN -0500, then this is not really TIMESHOWN minus 5 hours? I thought TIMESHOWN -0500 is taking that time and minusing 5 hours to get the end resulting time. But maybe I was wrong all along, and the TIMESHOWN is the actual time derived after subtracting 5 ??

Comment: TIME -0500 means TIME is in a timezone of minus 5 hours compared to greenwich UTC - that means TIME is 5 hours behind UTC. If you use UTC you have to add 5 hours to TIME to get **NEW_TIME -0000 (UTC)**

Comment: After -0500, It will take 5 hours for the earth to rotate and the sun get to the same position in the sky in UTC,

Comment: that makes sense. Thank you so much for a great explanation!

Comment: Do you know of a library that supports a few different string formats being passed in, or to some extent I would always need to define the directives ?